# Fan working non stop on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: nvidia, battery, fan, overheating

Before doing the 23.04 update (Lunar Lobster), fan on my laptop were loud, but they stopped sometimes...
After the OS update, they run non stop and they are loud, even during light work overload like browsing, writing programs or even execute simple ones.

I already tried to set up i8k, which should be specifically for Dell systems, but with no positive result. Even touching BIOS setting (Dell has some pre-set configuration like "Performance", "Quiet", "Cold") has produced no change.

I have also looked around and found that changing `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` could mitigate the problem, though the file is not present in my system, only the `thermal-cpu-cdev-order.xml` is.

I have also experienced some lower performance of battery, probably due to the costant usage of the fans: in a matter of 3/4h of not intense work, the battery discharge.

Can anyone please help me solve the problem somehow?

Some systems information:

**OS: Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64**

**Kernel: 6.2.0-25-generic**

**CPU: 12th Gen Intel i7-1255U (12) @ 4.700GHz**

**GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX570 A**, (I have proprietary driver installed, suggested by Ubuntu itself)

**GPU: Intel Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]**

Comment: Does the same problem occur when running Ubuntu from the live USB that you used to install Ubuntu?

Comment: I don’t know. A software engineer friend of mine installed Ubuntu for me. The first time I booted it on, Ubuntu was already on it. Though if it might help, the problem presented itself even with the previews Ubuntu version

Comment: It does help. Your laptop's fan is also noisy and it probably needs to be replaced.

Comment: Ok… The fact is that I just bought the laptop, is that possibile that fans are damaged? Furthermore, they do stop sometimes for a couple of seconds, couldn’t it be some settings problem or driver/package missing?

Comment: A bushing is a cylindrical sleeve that is used to reduce friction between two moving parts, for example in a fan. Over time, bushings can wear out and become damaged. This can cause the fan to become noisy or to vibrate excessively and slow down or get stuck. If the bushing is damaged, the fan should be replaced.

Comment: I contacted the support service of Dell, they told me that not having Windows installed they can do nothing... They told me it might be a drivers problem... Helpful support...